# using im2bw in iterations with high amount of images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold

i am working extracting data from images using Matlab, i use the function *im2bw* in gray images for use later bwlabel but  the threshold doesn't work in all images, by that the images gain noise and the data obtained isn't representative.
How i can configure the threshold for evitate that problem?the function *graytresh* doesn't give a good threshold, exist any other method to fix the problem? 
I work with a lot of images (more of ten thousand sometimes) and i can't run one by one. 
The images are of fishes swimming and i need to be careful.
Thanks for read my problem!.

I use *graytresh* in images bw like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPtPc.jpg
-Sometimes the distortion on images are too much  dropbox with images https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xve7oe84xcfj9yt/AACA0dYrK_m7o8Oie0KWWR-2a?dl=0 starter images, bin images with distortion and bw images

Comment: Try `otsuthresh`.

Comment: @NKN how is  `otsuthresh` different from `graythresh`? Both use Otsu's method, so the result will probably be exactly the same.

Comment: @JVidal So are you using the same threshold for all images? How do you find that threshold? Only on one image?

Comment: i use the same threshold for all images, i find one of reference  using _graythresh_ in several images then i calibrate the threshold manually, generally is near of the threshold _graytresh_. The images are similar and the threshold ideal for every image are close.

Comment: Please provide some more sample images - it is very hard to know if a method will likely work when we can only see a single image!

Comment: ok :D i  will post more images in a dropbox, stackoverflow doesn't leave upload more in the post

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xve7oe84xcfj9yt/AACA0dYrK_m7o8Oie0KWWR-2a?dl=0 here

Answer (score 0):

There are countless methods for determining binarization thresholds. It depends on the images. A general answer that works for any image cannot be given.

I suggest you pick a representative set of images and compare the results of most common thresholding methods.

It is also possible that a global threshold is not suitable at all. Also try local thresholding methods.

Read this for an extensive comparison on thresholding methods:
http://pequan.lip6.fr/~bereziat/pima/2012/seuillage/sezgin04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had a little attempt at finding the fish, and seem to get quite good results using a normalised Green-Blue difference - this is just the difference between the Green and Blue components, normalised to the range [0,1]. The steps I use are as follows:

- do an auto-level contrast stretch to space things out better
- calculate the normalised Green-Blue difference, (Green-Blue)/(Green+Blue)
- threshold at 25%

I just used **ImageMagick** at the command-line. It is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.  I am sure you can do just the same in Matlab:

```
convert fishy.jpg -auto-level -fx "(g-b)/(g+b)" -threshold 25% result.jpg
```

[image]

If I had 10,000 images to do, I would use **GNU Parallel** to get all my CPU cores working in parallel:

```
parallel 'convert {} -auto-level -fx "(g-b)/(g+b)" -threshold 25% results/{}' ::: fish*jpg
```

Comment: thank you for the advice, but i need more acurracy :(